# Loading yaml from file and join fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, yaml

I try to load a yaml file into an array but it fails with undefined method `join' for "a b c":String

```
# Check certain temporarily emails
# Throw notice not accepted use other email
require 'yaml'
bad_hostnames = YAML::load(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/bad_hosts.yml"))
if /^(#{bad_hostnames.join("|")})$/.match(host)
  errors.add(:email, "Please not use a disposable mailbox")
end
```

So i required yaml *before and on top of the model, controller where I load the yml in*:

```
require 'yaml'
```

Still same result, in rails console this works flawlessly, what am I missing?
The above code is inside my user.rb model, in console it works

EDIT:
bad_hosts.yml looks like (shortened) 1 provider the line

```
0-mail.com
10minutemail.com
30minutemail.com
4warding.net
```

Comment: What is the contents of your `config/bad_hosts.yml` file. The problem seems to be in there.

Comment: the contents of bad_hosts.yml i will add above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *`.yml`* file is not a [YAML](http://yaml.org/spec/) file.

This would make it `.yml` file.

```
- 0-mail.com
- 10minutemail.com
- 30minutemail.com
- 4warding.net
```

But when you want to load just a file line by line try the following:

```
lines = IO.readlines("#{Rails.root}/config/bad_hosts.yml")
# note: lines end in "\n"
```

Comment: This totally did it and it totally just diden't notice the changes in file structure, i based mine on application.yml thx for pointing out!